# Observer will not work in a behavior?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I found that only when I break out a `observer` into a behavior, no change will be detected. Are observers not able to be used in behaviors?

```
    <iron-ajax
      auto="[[activated]]"
      url="[[HOST]][[LISTINGS]]/[[listingNumber]]"
      handle-as="json"
      verbose="true"
      with-credentials="true"
      on-error="_error"
      loading="{{loading}}"
      last-error="{{apiError}}"
      last-response="{{listing}}"></iron-ajax>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'single-listing',
      behaviors: [ApiConstants, IronAjaxHelpers],
```

---

```
 <script>
  IronAjaxHelpers = {
    listingNumber: {
      type: Number,
      value: 0,
      notify: true
    },
    activated: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false,
      observer: 'setListingNumber'
    },
    setListingNumber: function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);  
      //this.listingNumber = id;
      if (newValue === true) {
        this.listingNumber = app.listingNumber;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your behavior's properties should be defined inside the `properties` field, but it's currently at the top-level of the behavior object.

You should declare the properties inside the behavior like this:

```
IronAjaxHelpers = {
  properties: {
    /** PROPERTIES GO HERE **/

    listingNumber: {
      type: Number,
      value: 0,
      notify: true
    },
    activated: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false,
      observer: "setListingNumber"
    }
  },

  setListingNumber: function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  }
};
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/wdgoeM)